# Proper Holomorphic Mapping implies Branched Covering

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Suppose $D_1$ and $D_2$ are two bounded domains in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\text{ }f: D_1 \to D_2$ is a surjective proper holomorphic map.  Then why is $f$ a branched cover of finite order?

Comment: What happens when $n=1$ ?

Comment: Not sure.  I want to consider $f^{-1}\{0\}$ and show that on $D_1$ minus this set that $f$ is a covering map.  I believe that I need to show that $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is a finite set, but I am not sure if that is true.

Comment: I'm not sure of your definition, but I would think asking $f$ to be continuous on the boundary (assumed to be smooth..). By the open mapping we would get that $f$ is continuous $\partial D_1 \to \partial D_2$ so it is a finite covering $\partial D_1 \to \partial D_2$ and hence $D_1 \to D_2$.

Comment: I don't have that f extends continuously to the boundary.  But if it did, why does it imply that $\partial D_1 \to \partial D_2$ is a finite cover and not an infinite cover?

Comment: If $n=1$, I'd say since $\partial D_1$ is compact, if $|f^{-1}(p)| = \infty$ then the $z_i, f(z_i) = p$ accumulate at some $z$. Also between $z_i,z_{i+1}$ there is always a $s_i$ such that $f(s_i) = p_2$, thus $f$ is discontinuous at $z$. I wonder if it works with $n=2$.

Comment: Here's an idea: exclude the set where $df(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ is of non-maximal rank. Such a set should be a proper closed analytic subset of $D_2$ (and therefore it's preimage in $D_1$ is also proper closed analytic), and on the complement of this set, the map is a local diffeomorphism by the implicit function theorem. I'm probably forgetting something or making a mistake (so please do let me know if you see something here), which is why I posted this as a comment rather than an answer at first.

Comment: What is your definition of a branched cover? Are you familiar with the (Ehresmann's) "stack of records" theorem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244086/why-is-a-holomorphic-map-between-compact-connected-riemann-surfaces-a-branched-c?rq=1