# Can you explain to me the relationship between those two definitions of branched covering on surfaces?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, surfaces, covering-spaces

I'm studying branched (or ramified) coverings between surfaces and the definition that was given in the book I'm reading is the following:
"Lets consider two closed and connected surfaces $M$ and $N$, we say that the fuction $f:M\longrightarrow N$ is a branched covering if there exists a finite set of points {$x_1,...,x_n$}$\subseteq N$ such that the set $f^{-1}(${$x_1,...,x_n$}$)$ is discrete and the restriction of $f$ to the set $M\setminus f^{-1}( ${$ x_1,...,x_n$}$ )$ is a topological covering."
Then I read that every branched covering is locally modeled on functions of the form $z\mapsto z^m$ and this can also be used as a definition for branched coverings.
I just can't find a proof for that, and I don't know where I could get it. Any advice/reference?

EDIT:
I see that the second "definition" is not so clear, that's because I actually didn't find a formalization of it, but I think it could go like this:
"Given two closed and compact surfaces $M$ and $N$, a function $M\longrightarrow N$ is a branched covering if it is "locally modeled" (I didn't even find any definition of what being locally modeled is, however I tried formalizing it below) on functions of the form $z\mapsto z^m$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $m$ is a positive integer. For any point where $m>1$ the point corresponding to $0$ in the target $\mathbb{C}$ is called a branching point. The branching points must be finitely many".
For the definition of "being locally modeled", I think it could be something along the lines of:
"Given two surfaces $M$ and $N$ and given a continuous function $f:M\longrightarrow N$, lets consider a point $y\in M$ and its image $x=f(y)$. If there exist:

1. Two open neighborhoods $V,U$ of $y$ and $x$ respectively
2. Two homeomorphisms $\varphi:V\longrightarrow D$, $\psi:U\longrightarrow D$ such that $\varphi(y)=0$ and $\psi(x)=0$ and $D$ is the unitary open disk centered on $0$
3. A function $p_y:D\longrightarrow D$

Such that $f\circ\varphi^{-1}=\psi^{-1}\circ p_y$, then we say that $p_y$ is a local model of $f$ in $y$".
If you have a better definition than this, that  maybe just captures the idea of being "locally modeled" on $z\mapsto z^m$, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The first one is a definition, the second one is a fragment of a definition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes I kinda expected that... I edited the question. The problem is that I couldn't find a formal definition of "being locally modeled", even in other articles that introduced branched coverings.

Comment: Your definition of "locally modeled" is correct. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244086/why-is-a-holomorphic-map-between-compact-connected-riemann-surfaces-a-branched-c/2247079#2247079) for a proof of equivalence in one direction.